# Android dev Dynamically changes in dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have dialog

```
popupBuilder = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
                popupBuilder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                popupBuilder.setContentView(R.layout.settings);
```

Now how can I change views from R.layout.setting dynamically?
something like

```
final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
final View tev = factory.inflate(R.layout.settings, null);
((TextView)tev.findViewById(R.id.skidki)).setText("Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
TextView dialogButton = (TextView) popupBuilder.findViewById(R.id.skidki);
```

Anyway, I recommend you to create the dialogs like Android says ;):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html